# How to get clicked item's child text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code that I am trying, the DOM structure will be same.
The DOM in loaded dynamically, that why I am trying with document click. We need to get the colour of the current clicked box. With jQuery its easy, unable find solution in javaScript. Can anyone help to resolve this?

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    const CTABtn = e.target.closest(".btn"); 

    if(CTABtn){
      alert('the color of the box');
    }

});
```

```css
.container{
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   justify-content:space-evenly;
}
.box{
   border:1px solid black;
   padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Red</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn">CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Green</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn">CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Blue</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn">Blue</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are able to find the clicked button, so go up to the ancestor `.box`, and then select the `h1` in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a lot easier if you just added the color as a data attribute on the button.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    const ctaBtn = e.target.closest(".btn[data-color]"); 

    if(ctaBtn){
      console.log(ctaBtn.dataset.color);
    }

});
```

```css
.container{
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   justify-content:space-evenly;
}
.box{
   border:1px solid black;
   padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Red</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn" data-color="red">CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Green</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn" data-color="green">CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Blue</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn" data-color="blue">Blue</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are multiple ways to do what you want to do, you can access the parent and get the child or reference a sibling

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    const ctaBtn = e.target.closest(".btn"); 

    if(ctaBtn){
      console.log(ctaBtn.closest(".box").querySelector("h1").textContent);
    }

});
```

```css
.container{
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   justify-content:space-evenly;
}
.box{
   border:1px solid black;
   padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Red</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn">CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Green</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn">CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Blue</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn">Blue</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with `closest`, but what you want to do is find the closest containing `.box` (rather than `.btn`) and then, from there, find the `h1` element in the box to get the text from it:

```
const box = e.target.closest(".box"); 
const h1 = box && box.querySelector("h1");

if (h1) {
    alert(h1.textContent);
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    const box = e.target.closest(".box"); 
    const h1 = box && box.querySelector("h1");

    if (h1) {
        alert(h1.textContent);
    }
});
```

```css
.container{
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   justify-content:space-evenly;
}
.box{
   border:1px solid black;
   padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Red</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn">CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Green</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn">CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>Blue</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn">Blue</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another, but a bit more complicated way of doing that:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    let curr = elements[i];
    curr.onclick = () => {
        alert(curr.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.innerText);
    }
}
```